# Pandas conditional statement returning only zeros

Tags: python, pandas, algorithmic-trading, trading, metatrader5

I am working with a DataFrame showing financial data. I created a class to easily test multiple variations of a strategy. I created a new column called "postion" that tests a conditional statement. At first I got the error " The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." but managed to solve that by iterating over each item.

But now all values of the "position" column are equal to zero, which does not make sense to me because there are multiple occurences in the dataframe where I can see that the condition is True. Here is the code:

```
        for bar in range(len(self.data)):
           if self.data['close'].iloc[bar] > self.data['max_high'].iloc[bar]:
             self.data['position'] = 1
           elif self.data['close'].iloc[bar] < self.data['max_low'].iloc[bar]:
             self.data['position'] = -1
           else:
             self.data['position'] = 0
```

Here is the output(attached image below):

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqHSW.png)

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You may want to abandon this approach entirely and research `.loc` `.groupby` `.shift` and so on in order to calculate this without looping like that.

Comment: `self.data['position'] = 0` assigns the *entire* column to that value

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I understand where I went wrong now and how I can improve the execution

Answer (score 0):

Don't iterate over your DataFrame, use `numpy.select`:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [data['close'].gt(data['max_high'), data['close'].lt(data['max_low'])]
data['position'] = np.select(conditions, [1, -1], 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will improve the execution using this